# I want to dynamically add 2 textboxes after pressing a button using ant design, store it in an array, how do I achieve that?

Tags: react-hooks, antd

[image]I want to dynamically add 2 textboxes after pressing a button using ant design as shown in the image, also remove the textboxes with (minus) button, store those data in array initialState, how do I achieve that ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-leakey-qzp8o

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";    
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

function DualInput({form}) {
  const {getFieldDecorator} = form 
  const initialState = []

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err , field) => {           
      initialState.push(field)     
      console.log(initialState)
    }
    )}

    const handleAdd = () => {

    }

    const handleMinus = () => {

    }
  return <div>
    <Form layout="inline" >
    <Form.Item label="Quantity">
  {getFieldDecorator("quantity", {
    rules: []
  })(<Input placeholder="Quantity" size="large" />)}
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="Price">
      {getFieldDecorator("price", {
        rules: []
      })(<Input placeholder="Price" size="large" />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
      <Button type="secondary" shape="circle" icon="plus" size="large" onClick={handleAdd}/>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
      <Button type="secondary" shape="circle" icon="minus" size="large" onClick={handleMinus}/>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
      <Button type="secondary" size="large" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
</div>;
}
const DualInput2 = Form.create()(DualInput);
ReactDOM.render(<DualInput2 />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Array I want to get (Sample):

```
const initialState = [{Quantity: "100", price: "100"}, {Quantity: "200", price: "200"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

change this functional component to class component. and update the state (array) by adding two entries as you wanted 2 new entries for add button every click.

By rendering as many formItems as array length, you will get the right number of fromItems.

Answer (score 0):

You have [an offical example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4x224mnrw4) of how it's done.

```js
remove = k => {
  const { form } = this.props;
  // can use data-binding to get
  const keys = form.getFieldValue("keys");
  // We need at least one passenger
  if (keys.length === 1) {
    return;
  }

  // can use data-binding to set
  form.setFieldsValue({
    keys: keys.filter(key => key !== k)
  });
};

add = () => {
  const { form } = this.props;
  // can use data-binding to get
  const keys = form.getFieldValue("keys");
  const nextKeys = keys.concat(id++);
  // can use data-binding to set
  // important! notify form to detect changes
  form.setFieldsValue({
    keys: nextKeys
  });
};
```

Comment: Its not a coding service, you got an example, try and ask a a question if you get stuck